# Performance testing resources

Tags: performance, load-testing

> Please share any good performance testing resources which you have come across in past or referred to while working or learning about performance testing.

Comment: While this may certainly be expert level, I think this is lacking either detail or research. I don't consider this to be harmful to the community, but this site is quite different than an information repository. Instead, it is a Question-and-Answer site. The questions are typically actual problems you're facing in a professional environment. Now, it could be that no one on your team knows performance testing and you want to learn about it. In that case I'd give more detail about what you're testing. That's one possible example of how this could be improved. Try to match it up to your real job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in web sites, and mostly from a front-end point of view, the best books I have found are:

- [High Performance Web Sites](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/)
- [Even Faster Web Sites](http://stevesouders.com/efws/)

both by Steve Souders.

Answer (score 2):

I loved the book [The Art of Application Performance Testing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596520662).  It gave me a good primer the first time that I was told that I would have to set up performance tests.  I also occaisionally tak ea look through the blog [OnLoadTesting](http://www.loadtestingtool.com/blog/) occaisionally for some general theory.

Comment: Thanks Lyndon. I have read the book and its indeed good. Apart from that I have also referred http://www.codeplex.com/PerfTestingGuide which is very comprehensive. I will have a look at the blog you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links to good resources, I recommend:

Free site dedicated to [performance testing](http://performance-testing.org) (lots of resources, articles, downloads, list of tools, etc.)

[25 Good Performance Testing Articles](http://loadstorm.com/25-Performance-Test-Articles)

Comment: Good informative links for novices.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Patterns and Practices folks have a great free book offering guidance for performance testing and loadtesting of web apps.   Despite coming from MS, it's not very MS centric and offers great advice for anyone doing perf/load testing of web applications on any platform (not just windows)

You can download the PDF file for free over at [this page](http://perftestingguide.codeplex.com/) on codeplex.com

Comment: As of March 2020 the codeplex link is not accessible. Looks like [this MS doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/bb924375(v=pandp.10)) is the same book?

Comment: Yes @EndyTjahjono that appears to be the same book.  Glad to see MS still has it available.   Most of the basic concepts of how you design a performance test have not changed since it was written, so it's still a great resource for those new to perf testing